# .htaccess rewrite rule is discarding my querystring

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

My URL is like

```
http://172.16.3.97:82/shop/t-shirts/full-zip-sweatshirt?options=367:731,368:737,369:741&custom_inscription=test
```

and I wrote rewrite rule like

```
RewriteRule ^shop/t-shirts/([a-zA-Z0-9\-@]+)\?*$ shop/product?path=35&product_id=$1&test=$2
```

I got only `full-zip-sweatshirt` in `$_GET` but I am not able to get other parameters.

How should I write Rule in .htaccess ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your rewrite rule for this :

```
RewriteRule ^shop/t-shirts/([a-zA-Z0-9-@]+)\?*$ shop/product?path=35&product_id=$1&test=$2 **[L,QSA]**
```

The flag "QSA" add the original query string to your query

Or maybe this one should also help :

```
RewriteRule ^shop/t-shirts/([a-zA-Z0-9-@]+)\?*$ shop/product?path=35&product_id=$1&test=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```